# Why is my background image hiding my keycode generator?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a keycode generator with a background image.

The keycode generator works fine, as does the background image, but the background image is displayed over the keycode generator in the browser.

I want the keycode generator to be displayed with the background image, well, in the background!

HTML body:

```
<div class="bg"></div>

        <div class="keycodegen">
        <h1 id='input1'></h1>
        <h1 id="input2"></h1>
        <h1 id="input3"></h1>
        </div>

JavaScript:

const input1 = document.getElementById('input1')
const input2 = document.getElementById('input2')
const input3 = document.getElementById('input3')

document.addEventListener('keydown', () => {
  input1.textContent = event.key
  input2.textContent = event.code
  input3.textContent = event.which
})

CSS:

body, html {
    height: 100%;
}

.bg{
    background-image: url("https://2static1.fjcdn.com/comments/Surely+one+of+these+new+found+egyptian+tablets+will+reveal+_5e782522453272e58724ef4ed55cbbfa.jpg");

    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    opacity: 0.5;

}
}

}

.h1 {
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;

}
```

Comment: Set the background on `<body>`.

Answer (score 1):

The div the background appears on is 100% tall.

The headings are not inside it: So they have to be **after** it.

If you want the background behind the headings, put the headings **inside** the element with the background.

(And the use of headings for this take is probably not a good choice. If you want to get user input, then use an `<input>`).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your background and headings in separate divs then you can position your `keycodegen` using css.

For example:

```
.keycodegen {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
```

You can change the positioning to your desired display.

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

.bg {
  background-image: url("https://2static1.fjcdn.com/comments/Surely+one+of+these+new+found+egyptian+tablets+will+reveal+_5e782522453272e58724ef4ed55cbbfa.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.h1 {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
}

.keycodegen {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg"></div>

<div class="keycodegen">
  <h1 id='input1'>example content</h1>
  <h1 id="input2">example content</h1>
  <h1 id="input3">example content</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the keycode generator within the background div